# SQLite DB Browser, can't modify column because trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I want to add a column to a table with DB Browser but when I try to save, I get this error message:

> Modifying this column failes. Error returned from database: Error
> renaming table 'sqlb_temp_table_19' to 'ClientData'.Message from
> database engine: error in trigger
> fki_ExclusionRoleClientDatas_ClientData_ID_ClientData_ID: no such
> table: main.ClientData (ALTER TABLE "main"."sqlb_temp_table_19" RENAME
> TO "ClientData")

The action I want to do is to add a column to 'ClientData' named 'RestartTime'. I don't have a table namend `sqlb_temp_table_19` and I dont have `'ClientData'.Message`.

The trigger exists with this content:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [fkd_ExclusionRoleClientDatas_ClientData_ID_ClientData_ID] Before Delete ON [ClientData] BEGIN DELETE FROM [ExclusionRoleClientDatas] WHERE ClientData_ID = OLD.ID; END
```

Whats is the error I get here?

Comment: Please add the code you are trying to do/run...

Comment: No code, just right click and 'Modify Table'.

Comment: Can you do it with code ? HERE: `ALTER TABLE ClientData ADD RestartTime int;`You can put whatever data type you want...

Comment: @VBoka Thats did strangly work, thanks for that.

Comment: You are welcome. It is not strange. Maybe you did not clicked on the right object or maybe you have tried to modify something else like table name, or who knows what. In this situations a capture screen would be nice... Happy to help.